# Expression has changed after it was checked -- ngClass change

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm not an expert in angular2. I would like to know how to resolve this error:

```
inline template:0:6332 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'btn-disabled'. Current value: ''.

 [ngClass]="!formValid() ? 'btn-disabled': ''"
```

what's your Ideas about this error ?

Comment: Can you post your `formValid()` method and things you might be doing early in the lifecycle that could change validity?

Answer (score 9):

try to use:

```
[class.btn-disabled] = "!fromValid()"
```

when use `[ngClass]`, you should return {class-name: true/false} map.

for example:

```
[ngClass]="{active: isActive, disabled: isDisabled}"
```